# How can I fit a trend line to a vector and plot it MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to fit a trend line to the `mt` vector and plot it using the code below, but I keep getting an error saying "Vectors must be the same length". If anyone could help push me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thank you.

```
years = 1900:2000;
mt = zeros(numel(years),1);

for yearnum = 1:numel(years);
   temp = T(year_one == years(yearnum) & month_one == 8);
   mt(yearnum) = mean(temp);
end

S = zeros([length(mt),2]);
S(:,1) = 1;
S(:,2) = years`;
P_fit = S\isfinite(mt);
fits = S*P_fits;

plot(years, mt, 'r-')
hold on
plot(years, fits, 'k-')
hold off
```

I'm not positive but I think the problem is that P_fits is 2 elements, the y-int and the slope, and I'm trying to plot that with years which is 100 elements.

Also, I realize that I could just check the box in the tools tab of the plot but I would like to obtain the error for the y-int and slope as well

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code.  Shouldn't `fits = S*P_fits;` be `fits = S*P_fit;`?  Also, `years` doesn't have the right character for transposing, i.e. `S(:,2) = years';`

Comment: @rayryeng Ok thanks for spotting those, I decided to put the `isfinite(mt)` before the `S = zeros...`line to remove a single NaN value that was in the `mt` data. But this NaN doesn't correspond with the 1 `year` I had to remove to get the dimensions to agree and to plot. I did `S(:,2) = years(1:end-1)';`. If I may I ask for your help again, I'm just trying to figure out a way to remove the NaN with its corresponding year